# How does (echo 'text' ; cat file.txt ) > new file.txt actually work?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, subshell

So, here's a simple code:

```
(echo "Some text to prepend"; cat gero.txt) > file.txt
```

And I can't really grasp the mechanics of this code. So basically gero.txt is an already existing file, we create a new file.txt with "Some text to prepend"+gero.txt
The thing I don't get is that part in parentheses. How exactly does it redirect the output of echo to cat with no evident operator like pipe `|` etc.?

Comment: Realllly strongly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators; the key element is the `>`

Comment: *"How exactly does it redirect the output of echo to cat"* it doesn't - it redirects the outputs of both `echo` *and* `cat` to `file.txt`

Comment: "does it redirect the output of echo to cat" .. it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a sequence of commands in the *interactive* shell, like

```
echo xxx; cat file; ls; echo yyy
```

then everything is executed consecutively and the output is send to the terminal.

But, if you run these commands inside parenthesis `()` a new *non-interactive* shell is created and everything is executed inside it. Now, with `>file.txt` after `()` you redirect the whole output from this hidden sub-shell to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The shell picks up that command line in three parts:

1. `(echo ...`)
2. `>`
3. `file.txt`

The (standard) output -- not any stderr output -- from part #1 is redirected by part #2 into the file given in part #3. The parenthesis in part one simply groups all of the output together for the redirection operator `>`.